# Upgrading to precompiled Handlebars 4.7.6 templates fails to render

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Since I upgraded to Handlebars 4.7.6 I'm getting an error trying to render my precompiled templates.  I upgraded the js runtime to the same version but my template fails to load.

This is the code trying to render the template:

```
var template = Handlebars.templates.index;
var rendered = template(data);
```

and the error: TypeError: template is not a function

When I inspect the differences in the code of a 4.7.3 compiled template I see that the older versions handles the object creation differently than the newer template. On the beginning of the file the templates are different:

ver: 4.7.3

```
!function(){var l=Handlebars.template;(Handlebars.templates=Handlebars.templates||{}).index=l({1:function(l,n,e,a,t){...
```

ver: 4.7.6

```
!function(){var l=Handlebars.template;(Handlebars.templates=Handlebars.templates||{})["handlebars.index"]=l({1:function(l,n,e,a,t){...
```

If I manually change ["handlebars.index"] to index then my template renders correctly. But I don't want manually to change the code of the template every time I compile a new one.

Is there something I can change on my code for making it work?

Comment: Check that you are using latest runtime and! check names for the precompiled templates. I did a quick check, the code very similar to your work as expected. I will provide an example if needed. And check do you have any errors while page loading except error with handlebars

Comment: @Drag13 I'm using the latest version 4.7.6 of the compiler and the runtime. No js errors otherwise, and the names are right. Does your runtime generates ["handlebars.index"]=l or .index=l ?

Comment: I don't see this at all. Let me clarify, are you using this code in HTML file or in Node.js 
Just in case, here is how I am using runtime for testing:```<script src="./node_modules//handlebars//dist/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>```

Comment: @Drag13 this is the javascript of the template file.

Comment: Excuse me? Don't get your point. Maybe you can provide more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see the compiled code of version 4.7.6 , You should try to retrieve `index` function as shown below.

```
var template = Handlebars.templates["handlebars.index"];
var rendered = template(data);
```

Let me know if that helps.